# Get HTTP Status Description from RestKit .20.3

Tags: ios, rest, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm able to get the status code just fine, but I'm looking for a way to get the ["HTTP Reason Phrase"](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html#sec6.1.1) from the response. I've spelunked through [RKObjectRequestOperation](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKObjectRequestOperation.html) and don't see it anywhere. I feel like I'm just missing it. Is this something that's supported by RestKit?

In my particular case, the service I'm hitting is sending this back:

```
HTTP/1.1 409 A user with this phone number already exists
Cache-Control: private
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 24 Feb 2015 22:13:21 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

I'm trying to get at the "A user with this phone number already exists" bit.

Thanks very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a RestKit thing, it's a URL handling system thing as it is the HTTP underpinnings that RestKit is built on top of.

So it should be provided by `localizedStringForStatusCode:` from the `NSHTTPURLResponse` that you can ferret out of the RestKit operation.

To be honest I've never had cause to use it so I'm not sure if it's purely a local client lookup from the returned status code or if it does link to any server response data. As the docs reference RFC 2616 it should pick up the text if the server sends it out...

Comment: Gotcha. I'll mark this as answered, because you're right, it's not a RestKit thing; it's definitely a lower-level HTTP thing. I'll re-ask the question in this context. I did, however, do as you suggested, but it appears as though the reason phrase is just a generic description that corresponds with the HTTP Status Code and not gleaned from the actual HTTP Response. Not surprising given that the localizedStringForStatusCode function is a static member of NSTTPURLResponse. Thanks for the note!

Comment: Yeah, an hour or so after answering I was thinking about it being a class method...